# Android Studio: Installation failed with message Invalid File

Tags: java, android

Installation failed with message

```
Invalid File: D:\TestApp%amp;amp;A\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
```

That is the entire error. I have no clue how to solve this. I have tried to clean and rebuild the apk but that does not help. I also tried running this on both my real phone and an emulator.

If anyone could help that would be amazing. Thanks!

Edit: I solved the issue, somehow (not really sure how). But now the app crashes as soon as I try to start it ;-;

Comment: I'm confused. What error are you getting when you run on your phone and emulator?

Comment: Have you try what is suggested? Uninstall the app from your device and reinstall it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to uninstall the app and reinstall it. But that doesn't do anything. I just get the same error over and over again

Comment: Just for testing can u change the project location to one that has no special characters on the route as space? Ex: from C:\Route W Space to C:\RouteWSpace

Comment: Ernesto, what do you mean? I don't understand